# Rails helpers aren't being loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm experiencing quite a strange problem with the loading of helpers in Rails.

I have several helpers in the `app/helpers` directory which don't get loaded each time the server is restarted. Only when I open one of the helpers and save it again will they get loaded.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: which server? thats pretty strange

Comment: Thin & WEBrick. I solved it though. I assumed, from reading old documentation that all helpers were always loaded in all views. I was very wrong. The bizarre thing is though that saving any helper made it available in all views.

Comment: i would suspect that in development mode there is code watching the helpers folder and evaluating the module regardless of if it should be included